# Symfony - Passing object in multipage forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to implement a multi-form multi-page function. For example I have an Experimentation (entity) which is linked to Data (entity) and Result (entity) with classic foreign key relations. I want to create a entry process like:

```
Experimentation entry (using Experimentation generated form)
Next
Data entry (using Data generated form)
Next
Result entry (using Result generated form)
Validate
```

The three entities are persisted (and flushed) only at the last step (validate).

I've tried the following code:

```
/**
 * Creates a new Experimentation entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="experimentation_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request) {

    $experimentation = new Experimentation();
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ExperimentationType', $experimentation);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $this->experimentation = $experimentation;
        return $this->forward('AppBundle:Experimentation:newData', array(
            'experimentation' => $experimentation
        ));
    }

    return $this->render('experimentation/new.html.twig', array(
            'experimentation' => $experimentation,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

In the same controller:

```
/**
 * Creates a new Data for the new Experimentation entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new/data", name="experimentation_new_data")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newDataAction(Request $request, $experimentation = null) {
    $data = new Data();
    $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\DataType', $data);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // Go to the "Result" entry using the same technique
        return $this->forward('...');
    }

    return $this->render('data/new.html.twig', array(
            'data' => $data,
            'experimentation' => $experimentation,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

It's look like symfony cannot render the second form (the data form based on the Data Entity):

> The merge filter only works with arrays or "Traversable", got "NULL"
>   as first argument in data/new.html.twig at line 1.

What I've tried to do:

- check variables with `var_dump`: there is NO null variable...
- replace forward by redirectToRoute: in this case, the form is rendered but I can't manage to "send" the experimentation object from method `newAction` to method `newDataAction`.

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across this issue and, as the error msg suggests, it was the ['merge'](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/merge.html) twig filter that was throwing.

Your `new.html.twig` template likely extends another template - check that base template for uses of `merge` (the error message `data/new.html.twig at line 1` is the giveaway, as line 1 will be your 'extends' statement).

In my case, I was doing the following, but `app.request.get('_route_params')` was null under certain conditions:

```
app.request.get('_route_params')|merge({'_locale': 'en'})
```